# Compile primary services for performance gain

Tags: performance, optimization

Greetings,

Is it worth it to compile primary services like Apache, MySql and on another note, the kernel to squeeze out more performance?

Ubuntu 10.04 64bit

// EDIT

I mean compile from source with architecture specific flags instead of using x86_64 binaries.

Cheers.

Comment: Uh? Are they not already compiled?

Comment: I mean compile with flags optimal to my processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my point of view, nowadays I would not recommend to compile such services unless you are trying to run them on a specific platform for which your distribution does not provide packages.

Distributions not only provide packages for a wide variety of architectures, but they also provide security fixes, which you might miss.

Unless you have specific needs, I would recommend against it (and back in the old days, I used to compile almost everything).

Comment: Sounds reasonable